# Pandas : extracting values from unknown data structure in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I have a pandas series, such that each row of the series includes a string with the following format (key - value structure):

> "Customer Name - Eric\nFamily Name - Lammela\n**Shirt** color - white\n\n"
>   field inside the string might change: 
>   "Customer Name - Leo\nFamily Name - Messi\n**Pants** color - black\n"

I would like to convert the whole series into a DataFrame.
What is the most efficient way?

Comment: How would you deal with it during importing?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. I have used the example you provided to try it out.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

# Stored your example in the string
s = pd.Series(["Customer Name - Eric\nFamily Name - Lammela\nShirt color - white\n\n","Customer Name - Leo\nFamily Name - Messi\nPants color - black\n"])

# Define a function to convert each string in the Series to a json format
def str_to_dict(txt):
    txt = txt.rstrip('\n')
    txt = re.sub('^', '{"', txt)
    txt = re.sub(' - ', '": "', txt)
    txt = re.sub('\n', '", "', txt)
    txt = re.sub('$', '"}', txt)
    return(txt)

# Apply the function to the Series and store the results in a new Series
s1 = s.apply(str_to_dict)

# Create an empty DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame()

# Loop through the converted Series and append the items to the DataFrame
# after using json to convert them to a dictionary
for c in s1:
    df = df.append(json.loads(c), ignore_index=True)

# Printed the df to check the results.
print(df)

  Customer Name Family Name Shirt color Pants color
0          Eric     Lammela       white         NaN
1           Leo       Messi         NaN       black
```

Hope this helps.